# How does "docker-compose down" know which contains should be removed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run `docker-compose up` multiple times within different terminals, then when I type `docker-compose down` in another terminal. How could `docker-compose` know which container should be closed?

The document doesn't describe the internal logic for this command.

Comment: Are you in different directories in those different terminals? AFAIK it just looks at the first `docker-compose.yml` it finds starting from your current directory and working up the filesystem tree, unless you specify a path to a `docker.compose.yml` file with a flag when you run it. Thus, if you're in the same directory in another terminal it will remove the containers that were started in the previous terminal, but if you're in a different directory with a different `docker-compose.yml` it will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose` read the config from `docker-compose.yml` , therefore you need always to start it from the same folder as  `docker-compose.yml` or specify the location with `-f`.

so `docker-compose` will stop the services which are in `docker-compose.yml`, or you can give the service name to `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose down myservice
```